# MS Access version of a Python melt

Tags: sql, ms-access, melt

Assuming a table organized thus:

```
Row |  School | LocationCode2011 |  LocationCode2012 | LocationCode2013 

001      ABC        1000A                1000B                2000X
002      DEF        2000A                2000B                4000X
```

With the intent to change it to this:

```
Row |  School |    Location        | Value

001      ABC    LocationCode2011     1000A
001      ABC    LocationCode2012     1000B
001      ABC    LocationCode2013     2000X
002      DEF    LocationCode2011     2000A
002      DEF    LocationCode2012     2000B
002      DEF    LocationCode2013     4000X
```

Python is my preferred language but I need this to happen in MS Access. In Python I would do

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=["Row","School"], value_vars=["LocationCode2011", "LocationCode2012", "LocationCode2013""], var_name="Location",val_name="Value")
```

and receive a new table stored in df2. I've looked for documentation on "melting" in Access and so far and I don't know if Transform is quite what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Access, this rearrangement of data to normalized structure can be done with a UNION query.

```
SELECT Row, School, LocationCode2011 AS Value, "LocationCode2011" AS Location FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Row, School, LocationCode2012, "LocationCode2012" FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Row, School, LocationCode2013, "LocationCode2013" FROM tablename;
```

First SELECT line defines data type and field names. There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines.

Then if you want it committed to a new table, use this query as source for a `SELECT INTO` action SQL or if table already exists, an `INSERT SELECT` action.

Comment: If I pseudocode this so that I'm understanding it right:
Select [id fields],
[First Field to Melt] as Value, "First Field to Melt" as First from tablename
Union Select [id fields], [Second Field to Melt], "Second Field to Melt" from tablename
(etc. for other fields to melt)
Is this correct?

Comment: That does seem to follow my suggestion, except for `First` alias name. First SELECT line defines data type and field names.

Comment: Works, also I should note that Access seemed to not like that I had the word "Row" as a column name, and I had to change it.

Comment: I would not have expected that to be a reserved word but apparently it is. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html